# Why Javascript acts like this?

Tags: javascript, increment

If I do:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a) // 1
console.log(++a) // 2
console.log(a++) // 2
console.log(a) // 3
```

So to try make sense of this I would say:

1. Assign 1 to `var a`.
2. `a` now is 1. So it prints 1.
3. Now, INSIDE function `console.log` I sum to a 1. So it should print 2. The sum happens BEFORE printing the value.
4. Why the value 1 is added to a AFTER printing the actual value of a? This is what I don't get.

How Javascript works so that this can happen?

Thank you!

Comment: is nothing unexpected, ++a is added before which is 2 from 1, a++ is added after so its still 2, then last is outputting 3 because it was added in prev line

Comment: Do you know the difference between *pre-increment* and *post-increment*? You may need to look more closely here. These have a different behaviour for a reason.

Comment: in number 3, when you say "I sum to a", you should instead say "I pre-increment a".

Comment: Didn't know that a console.log() could execute instead of just printing the variable

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between a pre-increment and post-increment.

`++a` will add 1 before the final value is evaluated.

`a++` will evaluate `a` and then add ` afterwards.

[See Increment (++) Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `a++` and `++a` is the value of the expression.

- The value `a++` is the value of `a` before the increment.
- The value of `++a` is the value of `a` after the increment.

So you can get the result as the question.